# Is there an equivalent to Array.Empty<T> for multidimensional arrays?

Tags: c#

Currently, I'm using `Array.Empty<Complex>()` when a method must return an empty array (due to boundary conditions).
I also have methods returning `Complex[,]`. In that case, I'm currently obliged to return `new Complex[0, 0]`.
If possible, I would like to standardize the code sending back empty arrays, whether they are of dimension 1 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing inbuilt, but you could readily create your own:

```cs
internal static class Foo<T> // naming is hard
{
    public static T[,] Empty2D { get; } = new T[0,0];
}
```